# Identifying equation from the type F(x, y(x), dy/dx )

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I have this equation:

$$
(y')^2+2y'+x=0
$$

I don't quite understand how to solve it and how to identify it. I am sorry if the question is dumb or irrelevant but what are these equations labeled as and where can I found how to solve them?

Comment: Sounds like from your comment below that the question is asking you to solve the differential equation. This equation is non-linear which may make it more difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You identify or classify it as an implicit differential equation. That it can not be easily rearranged into an explicit equation follows from the fact that it is quadratic in $y'$ and thus has in general $2$ values for every point $(x,y)$, so that no equivalent form $y'=f(x,y)$ can be found. Indeed, solving the quadratic equation as in the contribution of Max Payne gives $2$ possible explicit forms (that are additionally continuous).

---

Another solution method for some classes of implicit ODE searches a parametrization of the solution by the derivative $p=y'(x)$, using $x=X(p)$, $y=Y(p)$ with $$0=X(p)+p^2+2p,$$  $$Y(p)=y(x)=y(X(p))$$ and thus 
$$
Y'(p)=y'(x)·X'(p)=p·X'(p)=-p·(2p+2)\\\implies\\
Y(p)=-\frac23p^3-p^2+C
$$
which already completely describes the solution curves, but you can in this case simply eliminate $p$ to get a "classical" solution $y(x)$.

Comment: But how do you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Solve for $y'$ using quadratic formula.

$$y' = -1 \pm \sqrt{1-x}$$

Now it is a variable seprable equation.

Comment: Well, not quite the answer given is 2x = p^2+2p, where y = c+ 2p^3, it's not that simple... the problem is that the material is written in Bulgarian and I can't seem to find a way to translate it to english. The name of the material is callled differential equation not solved for the derivative

Comment: One class of ODE of that type are the [Clairaut ODE.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut's_equation) Interpreted as part of such one, $f'(p)=p^2+2p$ gives $f(p)=\frac13p^3+p^2$ for the Clairaut equation $y=xy'+f(y')=xy'+\frac13y'^3+y'^2$.

Comment: @LutzL I don't think that this question is of the clairaut form, please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: The question _could_ be the search for the non-linear solution $0=x+f'(y')$ of the reconstructed Clairaut problem, it has the correct format for that.

Comment: @Harton: Your formulas contradict the identity $y'(p)=p·x'(p)$ that follows from $y'(x)=p$.